# where to set xamarin forms master pages styles

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am a newbie following a book on `Xamarin` forms (xaml) and one example has a `ContentPage` with `ListView`:

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" RowHeight="100" BackgroundColor="Black" HasUnevenRows="true" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
               <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,10,5,15">
                  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Orientation="Vertical">
                     <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                     <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" WidthRequest="260">
                     <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="25" TextColor="Aqua" Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                     <Button Text="Buy Now" BackgroundColor="Teal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Command="{Binding BuyCommand}" />
                  </StackLayout>
               </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

I've created a project and copied the book's sample code to my project, so apart from namespaces the code is identical between the 2 projects. Both run but produce different visual results:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ListViewButton());
```

The source code displays the data in 3 column, perfectly aligned. My copied code presents the same data in 3 columns but they are not aligned vertically. Plus the `NavigationPage` has no header and has a white background. The source code has header information and a black background. I cannot find where these styles are set or any difference in the code between the 2 projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can find styles in resource dictionary that must be added in app.xaml file plese check

Comment: The is no App.xaml but rather App.cs. Please provide more details where the resource dictionary is found. For example is it in the XAML (portable) project or the Droid project?

Comment: it will be in portable project

Comment: and if there are any plateform specific design changes then for that there will be some customerendeder folder in android project

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I cannot see any relevant files. The portable project has nothing apart from app.cs and various XAML pages, which I've duplicated. The Droid project has Components, Assets and Resources. Where should I look to find why one project has a header, black background, aligned columns and the duplicate has no header, white background and unaligned columns?

Comment: have u copied xaml with their xaml.cs?is there any inline styles in page? have u checked?

Comment: or there are any values folder under resources..check that also

Comment: Yes, I've copied everything except namespaces. I checked and double-checked. The XAML for the sample page is already posted

Comment: Sorry. i cant find except seeing your project.but there is nothing big deal in it.. what u want  exactly white or black background and proper alignment of columns right? so rather than now searching it where it is in that sample project simply you can do it in 10 minutes.and if you want to know how exactly give styles then it should be in app.xaml file ..in resourse dictionry..

Comment: so now try it now your own to create style whatever you want to apply.. and if you  found any issue.feel free to ask